# The usage of the word "groove"

Tags: terminology

The first meaning is the narrow track where the stylus runs on records.

We often use the word *groove* to qualify the rythm, when it sounds right and feels good on jazz, funk, reggae music etc. Is it known when it starts to spread as the second meaning?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is a question about language and is more appropriate for http://english.stackexchange.com/ .

Comment: I think it is related to music history, but I kind of doubt that you can exactly pinpoint when this happened as I garuntee it was informal description for a while before it became common.

Comment: It's insane that this is close-voted, IMO.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the [Online Etymology Dictionary](http://etymonline.com/index.php?term=groove) it starts to take a figurative sense of **"routine"** in 1842.

Then we have:

- jazz slang *in the groove*: **"performing well (without grandstanding)** in 1932
- american slang *groovy*: **"first-rate, excellent"** in 1937
- teen slang groovey: **"wonderful"** in 1941

---

[*The New Grove Dictionary of Jazz*](https://global.oup.com/academic/product/the-new-grove-dictionary-of-jazz-9781561592845) by Barry Kernfeld states:

> Within jazz circles, Gold identifies the phrase **"in the groove" – which from around 1936 to 1945** (i.e., during the height of the swing era) was in widespread use in referring to **jazz performances which were "excellent" or, by extension, "sophisticated"** – and the term **"groove" – referring in the 1940s and 1950s to "routine, preference, style, source of pleasure"**.

( . . . )

> [groove] tends to operate with reference to styles **from the latter third of the twentieth century which utilize characteristic accompanimental ostinatos** drawn from African-derived dance music, whether African-American (e.g., soul, funk, disco, rap, hip-hop), Afro-Cuban dance music (e.g., salsa), or Afro-Brazilian (samba), or some other such fusion.